# Не работает .js файл на GULP сборке

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

**Хочу сделать простенькую конструкцию через .js**
**Проблема в том, что не могу его подключить, css нормально работает, а именно js не хочет**
**вообще не в какую НО: в исходном коде показывает, мол он подключен возможно все дело в ошибке, когда на кнопку "жмякаю"**
**В консоли пишет:** *TypeError: out is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick*

js:

```
function out() {
    var p;
    p = document.getElementById('out');
    p.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Код в html без базовой структуры:

```
    <p id="out">text</p>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="out()">Push</button>
```

P.s вот код с main.min.js - `function out(){document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="Hello World"}`

Comment: Вы скрипт к странице подключили? В заголовке говорится про gulp. Как он связан с ошибкой?

Comment: Да, .js подключен. Дело в том, что один и тот же код написан, только на обычном проекте он работает, а если засунуть его в проект со сборкой Gulp - там уже ошибка эта. (код идентичный)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что я не досмотрел - вся суть в плагине Panini. Нужно было путь к подключению main.min.js вставлять в index html относительно папок
того скрипта...